# Filter Dataframe and leave only two oldest records of the same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

```
id | object  |     date  |
===|=========|===========|
q1 | obj11   | 2021-06-21|
q1 | obj16   | 2021-07-21|
q1 | obj91   | 2021-05-21|
q1 | obj10   | 2021-04-20|
q2 | obj17   | 2021-04-21|
q2 | obj72   | 2021-04-21|
q2 | obj13   | 2021-05-21|
q2 | obj14   | 2021-06-20|
q3 | obj51   | 2021-06-21|
q3 | obj15   | 2021-07-21|
q3 | obj18   | 2021-05-21|
q3 | obj19   | 2021-04-20|
...
```

I need to leave only the 2 oldest rows of the same id, so the result will be like this:

```
id | object  |     date  |
===|=========|===========|
q1 | obj91   | 2021-05-21|
q1 | obj10   | 2021-04-20|
q2 | obj17   | 2021-04-21|
q2 | obj72   | 2021-04-21|
q3 | obj18   | 2021-05-21|
q3 | obj19   | 2021-04-20|    
...
```

How can I do it with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `sort_values()`+`groupby()`+`head()`:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#Ensure that 'date' column is of dtype datetime
out=df.sort_values(['id','date']).groupby('id',sort=False).head(2)
#OR(Since without sort=False it is giving you opposite result then:)
#out=df.sort_values(['id','date']).groupby('id').tail(2)
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output

Comment: The `sort=False` should be on the groupby, not the sort :)

Comment: @OmerM25 thanks sir..It was a typo fixed it **:)**

Comment: The first version (out=df.sort_values(['id','date']).groupby('id').head(2)) gives me the opposite result -> the newest rows, but the second one (out=df.sort_values(['id','date']).groupby('id',sort=False).head(2)) seems like working good

Comment: @ybondaohh...I was not sure so posted both...thanks for telling..updated answer **:)**

Answer (score 1):

For the future, please provide a way to re-create your dataframe so it'll be easier for us to solve this.

To solve your issue:

I'd first turn the `date` column into a `datetime` pandas object, then I'll sort it:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[D]')
```

Then I'd sort by the id & date descending so I'll have the top dates for each id:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[False, False])
```

Finally we will groupby the id and grab the first 2 rows from each group:

```
final_df = df.groupby(['id'], sort=False, as_index=False).head(2)
```

And all together it looks like this:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[D]')
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[False, False])
final_df = df.groupby(['id'], sort=False, as_index=False).head(2)
```

The reason this works is because we are sorting the most recent dates first for each id, which later on when we group and we give the flag `sort=False` we are preventing from the groupby to mess our sort.

Then we can simply use `head(2)` to grab the first two rows from each group (each id) which is promised to have the most recent dates.